# Is there a NOR operator in Powershell?

Tags: powershell, operators

How to formulate ($blnA) nor ($blnB)?
I didn't find any -nor operator in Powershell.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators, you need this: `!($a -or $b)`

Answer (score 4):

No, there is `-not`.

Use `-not($binnA -or $binB)` (or `!($binA -or $binB)`).

#### [Here's an online demonstration.](https://tio.run/nexus/powershell#VcrBCgIhFIXhtT7FYXChoC8QBLMpWk3tWoYjRsbgBXVoUT27TUlQq3v5z9dLznopznbKXrej9G8qaf6W9/tvWvkQrvDAltLGuovZj1fvCswhkfM5486ZsFqMWEOcODumULzZUS7ohEWkhGULeYUOZqDB36YQfTWRCiQWYZpQ9Vlf)

Answer (score 0):

[briantist](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3905079/briantist) has it right here.

PowerShell best practice suggests that you don't use aliases in code, so I would avoid using '!' in place of '-not' - unless you're interactive, of course.

For example:

```
if(-not($binA -or $binB)){
     Write-Output 'One or more variables do not exist'
}
```